# .Net Nametable (Namespace) Problem

Tags: .net, xml, namespaces

In .Net I do this:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMan = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
XmlNodeList nlImages = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//v:imagedata", nsMan);
```

And I get this exception:

```
Namespace prefix 'v' is not defined.
```

But if I break the process and write this statement:

```
xmlDoc.NameTable.Get("v")
```

I get "v" out, so the namespace is defined ...right?

Anyway, in order to get this to work I have to add this:

```
nsMan.AddNamespace("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
```

To get that XPath query to work (I checked and the v namespace is defined in  the source xml document), so why doesn't this work as it  seems it should?

Thanks for the helps,

-nomad311

Answer (score 1):

This is a quirk of how the XmlNode object works, and accesses Namespaces within an XML document.

Unfortunately, you must use an `XmlNamespaceManager` (as you're doing in your code posted in your question) in order to use namespaces within the XML document that you're processing.

From the [MSDN documentation for the .SelectNodes method of the XmlNode object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx):

> XPath expressions can include
>   namespaces. Namespace resolution is
>   supported using the
>   XmlNamespaceManager. If the XPath
>   expression includes a prefix, the
>   prefix and namespace URI pair must be
>   added to the XmlNamespaceManager.
>
> Note:
>
> If the XPath expression does not
>   include a prefix, it is assumed that
>   the namespace URI is the empty
>   namespace. If your XML includes a
>   default namespace, you must still add
>   a prefix and namespace URI to the
>   XmlNamespaceManager; otherwise, you
>   will not get any nodes selected. For
>   more information, see [Select Nodes Using XPath Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx.aspx).

For what it's worth, manipulating XML documents/nodes using LINQ-To-XML is much easier, and more "fluent".